# Consider $p(x,y)=3x^{5}+3y^{4}x^{4}+6xy+3y+12\in\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$. Is $p(x,y)$ irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$? And in $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I don't know how to see if there are any $q(x,y),r(x,y)\in\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ such that $p(x,y)=q(x,y)r(x,y)$ or not. The same in $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$. I bet it is easier to work in $\mathbb{Q}[x][y]$ and in $\mathbb{Z}[x][y]$, just because the degree of the polynomial becomes lower in such rings. But it does not seem factible to apply any criteria (Eisenstein, Gauss, etc.) Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can factor a 3 out. Doesn’t that show that it has factors in $\mathbb Z[x,y]? Note that 3 is not a unit in this ring.

Comment: Yes, that's true. But how do you know the rest of the polynomial is irreducible in Z[x,y]? I mean, isn't it necessary that both factors are irreducible?

Comment: @CarlosHervásRodríguez $p$ is reducible iff it can be written $p(x,y) = a(x,y) b(x,y)$ with $a$ and $b$ non-units. After factoring out the $3$, the other factor has positive degree in both variables, hence is not a unit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

1. Divide by $3$, get an primitive polynomial, so irreducibility over $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$ is the same ( yes, initially $f$ was reducible over $\mathbb{Z}$, since $3$ not a unit there)
2. Look at it as a polyn in $\mathbb{Z}[y] [x]$. It's monic ( in $x$) so if it were reducible, the factors must have degrees $<5$.
3. Assume you have decomposition in $\mathbb{Z}[y][x]$. Now give the value $y=1$. Get a decomposition for the poly $g(x,1)$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.
4. Check that in fact $g(x,1)$ is irreducible, and get a contradiction. ( work say $\mod 7$ or other way).

Comment: That was so helpful, thanks! So the conclusion is that $p(x,y$ is irreductible in $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ but not in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ because $3$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Q}$, right?

Comment: @Carlos Hervás Rodríguez: My pleasure! Yes, the reason was $3$. For primitive poly over $\mathbb{Z}$ , it's equivalent to the problem over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @CarlosHervásRodríguez You have it the opposite way, $p$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$, irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$.

Comment: Oh, yes, thanks. I sometimes use one word instead of the other... But yes, that is what I was trying to say.